# JUnit TestNG with Data Provider which include an anonymous function

Tags: java, junit, testng

I need to create unit tests in Java with the data provider so I found ***TestNG*** library which I can use for my purposes.

I need a suggestion about how to write the test where I need to pass in the data provider an anonymous function plus a couple of strings.
It looks like this:

```
@Test
@UseDataProvider("requestsProvider")
public void builder(RequestClass request, HttpMethod method, URI relativeUri) {
    Assert.assertEquals(method, request.getMethod());
    Assert.assertEquals(relativeUri, request.getUri());
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] requestsProvider()
{
    
    return new Object[][] {
            {
                    (param) -> { new RequestClass( apiRoot.key("test").relativeUri("myRelativeUri"));},
                    "get",
                    "test/myRelativeUri"
            }
    };
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Where you have `myAnonymousFunction` you probably need `new RequestClass(...)` but without seeing the code for your `RequestClass` it's hard to say much more than that.

Comment: Thanks Erik I am not sure only about the anonymous function, I'm new with Java, this is why ;)
So if I write it like this should be ok?
(param) -> { new RequestClass( apiRoot.key("test").relativeUri("myRelativeUri"));},